# Bluetooth headset profile changes to Off during calls

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth

Recently during calls on Zoom or Google Meet, my headset has changed automatically its profile on Pulseaudio from `HSP/HFP` to `Off`, such that I have to manually change it back to HSP/HFP during the meeting, however after few minutes the annoying behavior repeats again and the headset gets `Off`.

I have tried some issues:

- Added auto_switch profile to false on `default.pa` like [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth_headset#Disable_auto_switching_headset_to_HSP/HFP).
- Removed cookies and user config files on `~/.config/pullse`
- Looked for errors on syslog or pulseaudio log, starting it like `pulseaudio -vvvv --log-time=1 > ~/pulseverbose.log 2>&1e.log 2>&1`. They didn't show any event happening when the headset gets **off**.
- Tried using *blueman*.
- Removed device and added it again on `bluetoothctl`

None of them changed this annoying behavior, and I wasn't able to find more related issues on the internet. I really appreciate if anyone has a clue of what is happening or what else can I try. Thanks.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Kernel: 5.8.0-55-generic
Pulseaudio 13.99.1
Bluetoothctl: 5.53
Headset: Bose qc35
Laptop: Dell Inspiron 14-5457

Comment: What headset make, model? What machine (Bluetooth controller)? Kernel version? Everything up to date? Headset fully charged?

Comment: Hey @vonbrand, I updated the information on the question. Bose QC35, Dell 5457. Everything is up to date and charged.